# Keep sidebars spacing equal on both side

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get equal spacing on either side of each sidebar. I'd like it to be like: |  |sidebar|  |content|  |sidebar|  |. https://jsfiddle.net/db89880q/
Right now, the sidebars are not sitting with equal spacing on either of their sides.

[image]

```
.nav_projects {
  top: 30px;
  left: 30px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: -66px;
}

.nav_studio {
  right: -40px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;

}
```

Comment: And the problem you're having is?

Comment: @j08691 Right now, the sidebars are not sitting with equal empty space on their sides.

Comment: Ah! you think that rotating things 90 degrees is going to hide what is your real intent? You want to **center things vertically** and this is a deadly sin in the CSS religion. You should not try to center things vertically... because this is CSS. And don't dare using a table td with vertical alignment... that's even more offensive :-)

Comment: I like the minimalism of your example, but I fear it doesn't correctly reflect the actual codebase.  I used the domain half of your email to find the original site and found that it has a 990px container, but your fiddle's container is 58% wide.  This means that no matter how much pixel based adjusting you do, it will never look correct at most resolutions.  I suggest revising your example code to reflect a pixel based container.  Otherwise, I did have something working, but it doesn't really matter given the problem I've stated. https://jsfiddle.net/jmarikle/2gw14ygz/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the content with the sidebars inside a div. Then position it with `margin: 0 auto;`. Then inside the diff you can use `margin-left` and `margin-right` to leave space between the content and the two sidebars.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this personally.

http://codepen.io/midgitsuu/pen/QyOdGd

HTML:

```
<div class="outer_container">
  <div class="sidebar sidebar_left">
    <p>Left Sidebar</p>
  </div>
  <div class="center_content">
    <p>Center Content</p>
  </div>
  <div class="sidebar sidebar_right">
    <p>Right Sidebar</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  margin:0;
}
.outer_container {
  width:100%;
  height:500px;
  background:lightgray;
}
.outer_container div {
  height:100%;
}
.center_content {
  display:inline-block;
  width:80%;
  background:blue;
}
.sidebar {
  width:5%;
  background:red;
}
.sidebar_left {
  float:left;
  margin-right:5%;
}
.sidebar_right{
  float:right;
  margin-left:5%;
}
```

Basically, get a master/outer container that is set to 100% width (the body's width), then size, or apply margins to everything inside using percentages that ultimately equate to 100%.  This makes your site responsive, though at much lower widths, you'd probably want media queries to change the layout a bit.  I preferred using floats in your situation since it seems like you want the sidebars to be pushed up against each side, accordingly.